# About get Joomla article from database

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I use such code:

```
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM #__content WHERE alias = '$alias'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$fullArticle = $db->loadResult();
if(!strlen(trim($fullArticle))) $fullArticle = JText::_('ERR_ARTICLE_NOT_LOADED');
```

Article: `<p>1</p><p> </p><p>2</p>`
In database: `<p>1</p><p> </p><p>2</p>`
But it returns: `<p>1</p><p>B </p><p>2</p>`

Comment: I'm sure its a stupid question but are you sure you're loading the correct article?? Also what Joomla version is this?

Comment: joomla 2.5 correct article?! I don't understand?!

Comment: Well are you sure your calling the correct article out the database? Are you loading a similar article with the extra 'B' in?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code which is the Joomla 1.6+ database query method. Works fine for me.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$alias = "";
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('introtext')
 ->from('#__content')
 ->where('alias = '.(int) $alias);
$db->setQuery($query);
$fullArticle = $db->loadResult();
```

Then echo it like so:

```
echo '<p>' . $fullArticle . '</p>';
```

At first I was getting an error saying that `$alias` was undefined so I just defined it as nothing in my code, howeevr you can change it to whatever suits your needs.